# liquibase using maven with two databases

Tags: database, maven-2, liquibase

i have the following structure to run one database from maven:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db.changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/charm</url>  
                        <username>***</username>
                        <password>***</password>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

now i want to run another database in the same server with the name charm2. i tried this:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db.changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/charm</url>  
                        <username>***</username>
                        <password>***</password>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db.changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/charm2</url>  
                        <username>***</username>
                        <password>***</password>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and it does not work. does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: should work, what's the error?

Comment: org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: Failed to validate POM for project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you could try giving an `<id>` to each `<execution>`.  Something like

```
...
<execution>
   <id>charm</id>
   <phase>process-resources</phase>
   <configuration>
   ...
</execution>
<execution>
   <id>charm2</id>
   <phase>process-resources</phase>
   <configuration>
   ...
</execution>
...
```

If this does not work, you could update your question with the full stacktrace specifying the exact line that maven fails to validate the pom.