# liquibase using maven with two databases does not work

Tags: maven, multiple-databases, liquibase

This post describes how to update two databases from maven using liquibase:
[liquibase using maven with two databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865767/liquibase-using-maven-with-two-databases)
However, when I try the exact same configuration in my pom.xml (included below) it does not work. I get this error when running 'mvn liquibase:update':

```
The driver has not been specified either as a parameter or in a properties file.
```

Running with verbose set to true I get:

```
[INFO] Settings----------------------------
[INFO]     driver: null
[INFO]     url: null
[INFO]     username: null
[INFO]     password: null
```

so looks like the configuration is not being passed to liquibase. If the *configuration* part is outside *executions* it works, but that defeats the whole idea of having multiple executions - you would want to use different configurations for different executions.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5.0</version>

    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <id>one</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>update</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
          <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
          <url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/${database.development}</url>
          <username>wifi_offload_app</username>
          <password />
          <dropFirst>${liquibase.dropFirst}</dropFirst>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <id>two</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>update</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog-master-sbr.xml</changeLogFile>
          <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
          <url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/${database.development.sbr}</url>
          <username>wifi_offload_app</username>
          <password />
          <dropFirst>${liquibase.dropFirst}</dropFirst>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.12</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

Thanks,
Hari

Update after trying 'mvn process-resources' from Mark's comment. Here's the output from mvn updating both databases.

```
[hariharan@msg9]$ mvn process-resources
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Offload Manager Service
[INFO]    task-segment: [process-resources]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO] [liquibase:update {execution: one}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db1
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:47 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Create Database Lock Table
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:47 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Lock Database
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:47 PM liquibase.lock.LockHandler acquireLock
INFO: Successfully acquired change log lock
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:47 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Create Database Change Log Table
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:47 PM liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase checkDatabaseChangeLogTable
INFO: Creating database history table with name: `DATABASECHANGELOG`
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:48 PM liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase getRanChangeSetList
INFO: Reading from `DATABASECHANGELOG`
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:48 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Changeset liquibase/changelogs/1328053095_tables.xml::1328053095-1::hariharan::(MD5Sum: bf33ef8ba7352e8c0864e9457ee642b)
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:49 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Changeset liquibase/changelogs/1328053095_tables.xml::1328053095-2::hariharan::(MD5Sum: 7cc4f84be549dbcea3589d85df3e059)
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Changeset liquibase/changelogs/1328053095_tables.xml::1328053095-3::hariharan::(MD5Sum: 59821447f5744410a1c36bccd16196f6)
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Release Database Lock
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.lock.LockHandler releaseLock
INFO: Successfully released change log lock
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Release Database Lock
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.lock.LockHandler releaseLock
INFO: Successfully released change log lock
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] [liquibase:update {execution: two}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/db2
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Create Database Lock Table
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Lock Database
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.lock.LockHandler acquireLock
INFO: Successfully acquired change log lock
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Create Database Change Log Table
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase checkDatabaseChangeLogTable
INFO: Creating database history table with name: `DATABASECHANGELOG`
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase getRanChangeSetList
INFO: Reading from `DATABASECHANGELOG`
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Changeset liquibase/changelogs-sbr/1330991147_tables.xml::1330991147-1::hariharan::(MD5Sum: 8cf69599bcf338b57d7fe1ecc1471d86)
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Changeset liquibase/changelogs-sbr/1330991147_tables.xml::1330991147-2::hariharan::(MD5Sum: cf9a9717987fda5deba07a7a943673e1)
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Release Database Lock
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.lock.LockHandler releaseLock
INFO: Successfully released change log lock
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate comment
INFO: Release Database Lock
Mar 7, 2012 4:11:50 PM liquibase.lock.LockHandler releaseLock
INFO: Successfully released change log lock
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 07 16:11:50 PST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/180M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does your build need to update 2 databases in one go? An alternative approach is to use Maven profiles as follows:

```
mvn process-resources
mvn -Pdb2 process-resources
```

## Project files

```
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- resources
            |-- com
            |   `-- myspotontheweb
            |       `-- db
            |           `-- changelog
            |               |-- db-changelog-1.0.xml
            |               `-- db-changelog-master.xml
            `-- liquibase.properties
```

I prefer to use Maven's *generate-resources* phase to create a liquibase properties file.

### pom.xml

Contains two profiles at the end containing the properties associated with the two databases. This solution scales to any number of db environments.

Another item of note is that liquibase uses the populated properties under the *targets* directory

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myspotontheweb.db</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.162</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyFile>target/classes/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                            <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>db1</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <liquibase.url>jdbc:h2:target/db1/liquibaseTest;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</liquibase.url>
                <liquibase.driver>org.h2.Driver</liquibase.driver>
                <liquibase.username>user</liquibase.username>
                <liquibase.password>pass</liquibase.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>db2</id>
            <properties>
                <liquibase.url>jdbc:h2:target/db2/liquibaseTest;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</liquibase.url>
                <liquibase.driver>org.h2.Driver</liquibase.driver>
                <liquibase.username>user</liquibase.username>
                <liquibase.password>pass</liquibase.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

### liquibase.properties

This is the template file populated with the profile property values for the specific environment.

```
# Database credentials
url=${liquibase.url}
driver=${liquibase.driver}
username=${liquibase.username}
password=${liquibase.password}

# Liquibase changelog
changeLogFile=com/myspotontheweb/db/changelog/db-changelog-master.xml
```

---

## Update

And alternative strategy would be to run the plug-in directly, instead of integrating it into a Maven life-cycle.

```
mkdir target
mvn liquibase:update
mvn -Pdb2 liquibase:update
```

Again you are using a profile to control the property settings.

### pom.xml

The difference is that the plug-ins settings are controlled by properties set in the profile. No more properties file created under the targets directory for shipment in your jar.

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myspotontheweb.db</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.162</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>${liquibase.url}</url>
                    <driver>${liquibase.driver}</driver>
                    <username>${liquibase.username}</username>
                    <password>${liquibase.password}</password>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/com/myspotontheweb/db/changelog/db-changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>db1</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <liquibase.url>jdbc:h2:target/db1/liquibaseTest;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</liquibase.url>
                <liquibase.driver>org.h2.Driver</liquibase.driver>
                <liquibase.username>user</liquibase.username>
                <liquibase.password>pass</liquibase.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>db2</id>
            <properties>
                <liquibase.url>jdbc:h2:target/db2/liquibaseTest;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</liquibase.url>
                <liquibase.driver>org.h2.Driver</liquibase.driver>
                <liquibase.username>user</liquibase.username>
                <liquibase.password>pass</liquibase.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for the very detailed response. Yes I need to update two databases on two different database servers from the same pom.xml.  I'll try profiles & report the results.

Comment: When I tried 'mvn process-resources', the pom I posted above worked as is! Both databases were updated in a single invocation of mvn. Maven appears to be a fairly complex tool. I'm still figuring it out. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: @ThiagarajanHariharan "process-resources" is the standard Maven phase which we have both plugged the liquibase plugin into.

Comment: I see that process-resources is part of the default lifecycle. In my case, is it possible to get 'mvn liquibase:update', which is one of the liquibase plugin's goal, to work (i.e. update both databases)? One side effect of having 'mvn process-resources' update the databases is that when I start jetty with 'mvn jetty:run -P jetty', it runs process-resources also, which updates the databases - it's harmless because liquibase knows the database has already been updated, but still it would be nice to not update the databases when starting jetty.

Comment: @ThiagarajanHariharan If you don't want the plugin to execute as part of the default lifecycle, then remove the "executions" configuration. Plug-in goal can then be just called.

Comment: If you remove 'executions' and run liquibase:update, how can you have two different configurations for the two databases? Will your profiles approach work?

Comment: @ThiagarajanHariharan The plugin part of the POM can still have a configuration section, but will need to use properties. These properties can then be assigned different values by the two profiles.

Comment: Perfect - just what I need. Works great. Having the properties in pom.xml itself avoids having to use an external properties file also. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkO'Connor What if we need to run scripts in a mixed order? In my case I need to run one script from `db1`, then `db2`, then again `db1`, then again `db2` , unfortunately objects from two different datasources have dependencies to each other

Comment: @mCeviker Don't understand the dilemma. Ideally you should be able to apply the changesets to all your database instances. Perhaps you could pose a new question and outline the scenario.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Yes I did that : Liquibase - multiple datasources in a mixed order http://stackoverflow.com/q/43720347/2815227

Comment: hi @MarkO'Connor! thanks for your detailed example! 

do you have an idea how to run diff/update for two postgres schemas (public/audit) at once?