# Liquibase + Maven: How to keep both testing DB and developing DB updated during mvn build?

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

I am very new using liquibase.

I have a JSP web application (no framework used), and I use a mysql db schema for testing and other one for developing.

I want to know how can I configure liquibase maven plugin to update both DB's on building time.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606585/liquibase-using-maven-with-two-databases-does-not-work/9609848#9609848

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the  **context** attribute for this sort of things. More details here http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html

To update both DBs, the maven commands would look like the following:

```
mvn liquibase:update -Dliquibase.contexts=dev

mvn liquibase:update -Dliquibase.contexts=test
```