# Loading data from properties file to be used by Liquibase in Maven build

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

I can run Liquibase changelog through maven build (`liquibase:update` goal) without any problems. Now I'd like Liquibase to use database credentials and URL loaded from a properties file (*db.properties*) depending on the selected Maven profile:

```
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- resources
            |-- local
            |   `-- db.properties
            |-- dev
            |   `-- db.properties
            |-- prod
            |   `-- db.properties
            `-- db-changelog-master.xml
            `-- db-changelog-1.0.xml
```

Each of the 3 properties files would look like the following:

```
database.driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
database.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host_name>:<port_number>/instance
database.username = user
database.password = password123
```

Now, instead of these properties being defined in the POM file itself (as explained in the accepted answer of this question [liquibase using maven with two databases does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606585/liquibase-using-maven-with-two-databases-does-not-work)), I'd like them to be loaded from the external properties file. I have tried different approaches to no avail:

**1. I used Maven's `resource` element in the POM file:**

```
<build>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
               <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.1.0</version>
               <configuration>
                  <changeLogFile>db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                  <verbose>true</verbose>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
   </build>


<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/local</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <liquibase.url>${database.url}</liquibase.url>
            <liquibase.driver>${database.driver}</liquibase.driver>
            <liquibase.username>${database.username}</liquibase.username>
            <liquibase.password>${database.password}</liquibase.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/dev</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <liquibase.url>${database.url}</liquibase.url>
            <liquibase.driver>${database.driver}</liquibase.driver>
            <liquibase.username>${database.username}</liquibase.username>
            <liquibase.password>${database.password}</liquibase.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**2. I tried using the Properties Maven plugin:**

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
               <files>
                  <file>src/main/resources/local/db.properties</file>
               </files>
            </configuration>
         </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
```

When I run the liquibase:update maven goal, I get this this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.1.0:update (default-cli) on project my-project: The driver has not been specified either as a parameter or in a properties file
```

It seems that the database properties referred to in the POM file couldn't be resolved.

Any idea how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I managed to get this working. The key was to use the maven *filter* element in conjunction with the *resource* element as explained in [Liquibase Documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/using-liquibase-and-maven-pom-file.html).

Also it's important to include the *resources* goal in the maven command:

```
mvn resources:resources liquibase:update -Plocal
```

This is the file hierarchy I used:

```
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
       |-- resources
       |   `-- liquibase.properties
       |   |-- changelog
       |       `-- db-changelog-master.xml
       |       `-- db-changelog-1.0.xml
       |-- filters
           |-- local
           |   `-- db.properties
           |-- dev
           |   `-- db.properties
```

The db.properties file would look like the following:

```
database.driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
database.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host_name>:<port_number>/instance
database.username = user
database.password = password123
```

The liquibase.properties file would look like the following:

```
changeLogFile: changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
driver: ${database.driver}
url: ${database.url}
username: ${database.username}
password: ${database.password}
verbose: true
```

The POM file would look like the following:

```
<build>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
               <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.1.0</version>
               <configuration>
                  <propertyFile>target/classes/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
   </build>


<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/filters/local/db.properties</filter>
            </filters>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/filters/dev/db.properties</filter>
            </filters>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: the liquibase documentation link is broken

Comment: are the username and password mentioned in liquibase.properties same as username and password of db.properties ?

Comment: Yes. `liquibase.properties` is referring to the values defined in `db.properties` via their respective keys `database.username` and `database.password`