# How to use liquibase:diff to migrate production database

Tags: liquibase

The development database is managed by liquibase. The production database is still empty. Based on the documentation I ran `mvn liquibase:diff` to get the differences between the development and production databases. The command generates a database changelog in xml containing a list of changeset.

I guess the next step is to use that diff change log and apply it to the production database. But I can't find the correct maven command to run in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the update command as documented here: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_update.html

Comment: If I use the update, it's going to update my developement database. So maybe it's the update command but what parameters would update the production database. This is what is not clear in the documentation.

Comment: Aha - yes, you will need to have different sets of parameters for each of the different databases that you work with. This question has some details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355725/loading-data-from-properties-file-to-be-used-by-liquibase-in-maven-build