# How to configure Liquibase plugin for two DB?

Tags: java, database, maven, database-migration, liquibase

How to configure `Liquibase plugin` with `Maven project` for the two `DB` (`MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`)?

I configured `liquibase` only `MySQL DB`. Also need for `PostgreSQL DB`.

Properties for `PostgreSQL DB`:

```
driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgresql_db
username = postgres
password = root
```

- `pom.xml`:

  ```
  <build><plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
          <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.4.1</version>
          <configuration>
              <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/dbliquibase/dbchangelog.xml</changeLogFile>
              <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
              <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql_db</url>
              <username>root</username>
              <password>root</password>
              <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins></build>
  ```

Comment: have you tried defining 2 [`executions`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) and configuring one for each of the databases?

Answer (score 0):

the plugin you can declare as many times as it is linked to an implementation phase, you also have the possibility to use a plugin that launches a dynamic ways and multiple times a plugin iteration iterator-maven-plugin :

http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/

Personally I do not recommend these solutions , I in your place, I created two profiles and I run either :

[liquibase using maven with two databases does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606585/liquibase-using-maven-with-two-databases-does-not-work)

Want to two different databases with a single run contrary to the fundamental principle of separation of responsibility in Java