# Liquibase - multiple datasources in a mixed order

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

It is said that we can run multiple datasources with the below spring beans

```
<bean id="liquibase1" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
      <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db1-changelog.xml" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="liquibase2" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
      <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db2-changelog.xml" />
 </bean>
```

or with the below pom.xml profiles

```
 <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>db1</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <liquibase.url>jdbc:h2:target/db1/liquibaseTest;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</liquibase.url>
                <liquibase.driver>org.h2.Driver</liquibase.driver>
                <liquibase.username>user</liquibase.username>
                <liquibase.password>pass</liquibase.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>db2</id>
            <properties>
                <liquibase.url>jdbc:h2:target/db2/liquibaseTest;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</liquibase.url>
                <liquibase.driver>org.h2.Driver</liquibase.driver>
                <liquibase.username>user</liquibase.username>
                <liquibase.password>pass</liquibase.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

What if we need to run scripts in a mixed order? In my case I need to run one script from `dataSource1`, then `dataSource2`, then again `dataSource1`, then again `dataSource2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this  by using the same data source many times with different bean injections as below

```
<bean id="liquibase1" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
      <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db1-changelog1.xml" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="liquibase2" depends-on="liquibase1" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
      <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db2-changelog1.xml" />
 </bean>
<bean id="liquibase3" depends-on="liquibase2"  class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
      <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db1-changelog2.xml" />
 </bean>
<bean id="liquibase4" depends-on="liquibase3"  class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
      <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db2-changelog2.xml" />
 </bean>
```

It is a good idea to put these bean definitions in a separate xml configuration file and import it